# Is the ClearAsync method atomic?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I had some questions about the [IReliableCollection.ClearAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.collections.ireliablecollection-1.clearasync?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Collections.IReliableCollection%601.ClearAsync);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=azure-dotnet) method. I could not find the answers for this in the documentation.

- Can we assume it is an atomic operation?
- What happens if the node hosting the partition with the reliable collection crashes during, or right after the method is called? Is it possible for the collection to contain a subset of the older items due to such crashes?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The idea of reliable collections is that all operations, absent exceptions, are persistent and replicated. The confusion is probably arising from the fact that `ClearAsync` doesn't take a `ITransaction` parameter (doesn't support undoing), but nothing in the documentation indicates it offers anything less than the strong consistency guarantees of every other operation.

In short, the answer to your first question is yes, you can consider it atomic; the second question follows.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections).